# Get twitter email Id on my web site

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

How can I get twitter email Id on my web site.

I am using twitter4j api.
But while getting email it shows

**Email: Twitter does not provide this!**

**In twitter4j api no method available to get email**

```
user = twitter.showUser(twitter.getId());

twitterUser = new TwitterUser(user.getId(),user.getName(),user.getScreenName(),user.getLocation(),
                    user.getDescription(),user.getProfileImageURL().toString(),
                    user.getFollowersCount(),user.getFriendsCount(),user.getFavouritesCount(),user.getStatusesCount(),
                    user.getListedCount(),user.getCreatedAt().toString(),user.getTimeZone(),user.getUtcOffset(),
                    user.getLang(),user.getURL()!=null?user.getURL().toString():null);
```

Is there any way to get this.

**Is there any othe api to get email and /FirstName/LastName .**

Please suggest any solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter does not provide an API for email retrieval. From their [FAQ](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/faq#6718):

> **How do I obtain a user's email address?**
>
> If you'd like a user's email address, you'll need to ask a user for it within the confines of your own application and service. The Twitter API does not provide the user's email address as part of the OAuth token negotiation process nor does it offer other means to obtain it.

If you have a user's ID or screen name, you can get any additional information from the Twitter4J [`User`](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/User.html) interface.